# Calculate Monthly Churn

Tags: python, pandas, churn

I am wanting to obtain a monthly customer churn rate by using the following formula:

(Number of Customers Lost within 1-month period / Number of Active Customers at the beginning of the 1-month period)

Say I have the following data (this is just a small sample of it - note that if "Boolean == True" the customer has left, otherwise False)

| start_date | Boolean |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-10-02 | False |
| 2015-10-04 | False |
| 2015-10-05 | True |
| 2015-10-06 | True |
| 2015-10-08 | True |
| 2015-10-08 | True |
| 2015-10-08 | False |
| 2015-10-08 | False |
| 2015-10-08 | True |
| 2015-10-08 | False |

What I would like to do is use the above-stated formula to obtain a time-series graph to plot the monthly customer churn overtime (which would be the monthly customer churn *across all years in the dataset*)

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the data stored in an array:

```
Boolean = [False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, False]
```

the solution is a simple one-liner:

```
sum([1 for x in Boolean if x])/len(Boolean)
```

Comment: What if the Boolean values were a Series (i.e., a column in a dataframe)? How would I group together the occurrences of "True" and "False" by month to get the churn rate?